# Extracting Country Names from Cell Values

Tags: vba, excel

This fairly clunky looking VBA script successfully pulls names of countries from an Array, but could it be made shorter?

Mass of text from Column C onward in each row may contain the names of countries, which I want to pull into the corresponding cell in row A. What I have so far is not pretty...

```
Sub PullCountries()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Block As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

While i <= LastRow
Set Rng = Range("B" & i)
Set Block = Rows(i)

Range("I1").Value = i

If InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Canada") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Canada") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Canada") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Canada"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "United States") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "United States") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "United States") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "United States"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Britian") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Britian") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Britian") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "UK"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "UK") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "UK") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "UK") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "UK"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Spain") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Spain") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Spain") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Spain"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Portugal") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Portugal") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Portugal") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Portugal"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Ireland") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Ireland") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Ireland") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Ireland"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Japan") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Japan") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Japan") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Japan"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Greece") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Greece") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Greece") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Greece"
i = i + 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Italy") Or InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Italy") Or InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Italy") Then
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Italy"
i = i + 1

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Offset(0, 1)) = 0 Then
i = i + 1

Else: i = i + 1
End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Obviously, this isn't pretty. And given that the task is very repetitive, I reckon it could be made shorter. If this is possible, how could I start.

Furthermore, would it be possible to pull from an array of countries pre-prepared in another worksheet, and refer to that instead of inserting the actual names into the code, as is done here? And finally, if a range contained more than one country, how could I expand the code to pull that information too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The small(er) things before we tackle the elephant in the room:

**Naming**

Your names aren't terrible, but could be a lot better. However, whatever you name things, you should comply with **standard naming conventions**. To wit:

> **Local Variables:** Written in `camelCase`.
>
> `Dim localVariable As String`
>   includes method arguments.
>
> **Module / Global Variables:** Written in `PascalCase`.
>
> `Private ModuleVariable As String`
>   `Global PublicVariable As Long`
>
> **Method Names:** Verbs. Written in `PascalCase`
>
> `Private Function ReturnThisValue() As Long`
>   `Public Sub DoThisThing()`
>
> **Constants:** Written in `SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE`
>
> `Public Const CONSTANT_VALUE As String = "This Value Never Changes"`

Also, `Block` is declared and set but never used. It should be removed.

---

**Don't use `:`**

Just don't. Keep your instructions on separate lines. They're too easy to miss and violate too many conventions.

---

**Put things in Variables**

```
Range("C" & i)
```

You see this? This is telling Excel to go and find that range. **Every** time you write it. What if you want to check a different column? Right now, you'll have to rewrite the declaration on 20 different lines.

Instead, put it in a variable then just reference the Variable. Now, if the variables need to change, you only have to change them in **1** place, and the rest takes care of itself.

```
Dim cCell As Range, dCell As Range, eCell As Range
Set cCell = Range("C" & i)
Set dCell = Range("D" & i)
Set eCell = Range("E" & i)

Dim countryName As String

countryName = "Canada"
If Instr(1, cCell, countryName) Or Instr(1, dCell, countryName) Or Instr(1, eCell, countryName) Then
...
...
```

---

**Don't Repeat Yourself**

Also known as DRY. Take your `i = i + 1` statement. That is **always** going to happen. So why write it 20 times when you can just put it at the start or end of your loop?

```
While i <= lastRow

    Code
    Code
    Code

    ...

    i = i + 1

Wend
```

Boom. 12 lines of code gone

---

And now the big stuff:

### **Refactoring**

Refactoring is the process of splitting one big thing into many little things. 
**Any** time you find yourself copy-pasting code, you should be thinking "Hmm, this can probably be turned into a method of some kind".

---

### **1st Refactoring**

This check:

```
If Instr(1, cCell, countryName) Or Instr(1, dCell, countryName) Or Instr(1, eCell, countryName) Then
```

Can be a Separate Method Like so:

```
Public Function NameIsInRange(ByVal searchName As String, ByRef range1 As Range, range2 As Range, range3 As Range) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = InStr(1, range1, searchName) Or InStr(1, range2, searchName) Or InStr(1, range3, searchName)

    NameIsInRange = result

End Function
```

And now we're down to:

```
Sub PullCountries()

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

    While i <= LastRow

        Dim resultRange As Range
        Set resultRange = Range("A" & i)

        Dim cCell As Range, dCell As Range, eCell As Range
        Set cCell = Range("C" & i)
        Set dCell = Range("D" & i)
        Set eCell = Range("E" & i)

        If NameIsInRange("Canada", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "Canada"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("United States", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "United States"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("Britian", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "UK"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("UK", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "UK"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("Spain", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "Spain"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("Portugal", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "Portugal"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("Ireland", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "Ireland"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("Japan", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "Japan"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("Greece", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "Greece"

        ElseIf NameIsInRange("Italy", cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
        resultRange = "Italy"

        End If

        i = i + 1

    Wend

End Sub

Public Function NameIsInRange(ByVal searchName As String, ByRef range1 As Range, range2 As Range, range3 As Range) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = InStr(1, range1, searchName) Or InStr(1, range2, searchName) Or InStr(1, range3, searchName)

    NameIsInRange = result

End Function
```

---

### **2nd Refactoring**

The only things that actually change in the loop are the name to check and the name to output. So, why don't we make those a list? For an iterable list with more than 1 element per line, I'd use an `Array`.

Let's make a new sheet and give it the **codename** `wsCountryNames`. Then a function to get the table and pass it to an Array:

[image]

```
Public Function GetCountryNamesTable() As Variant

    With wsCountryNames

        Dim topLeftCell As Range
        Set topLeftCell = .Cells(1, 1) '/ "A1"

        Dim finalRow As Long
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, topLeftCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim tableWidth As Long
        tableWidth = 2

        Dim tableRange As Range
        Set tableRange = .Range(topLeftCell, Cells(finalRow, topLeftCell.Column + tableWidth - 1))

    End With

    GetCountryNamesTable = tableRange

End Function
```

The value in Cell `A1` is now in `GetCountryNamesTable(1, 1)`, `A2, (2, 1)`, `B1, (1, 2)` etc.

**Now**, we can just iterate through your list:

```
Sub PullCountries()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    i = 1

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim namesList As Variant
    namesList = GetCountryNamesTable

    Dim searchName As String, displayName As String

    While i <= LastRow

        Dim resultRange As Range
        Set resultRange = Range("A" & i)

        Dim cCell As Range, dCell As Range, eCell As Range
        Set cCell = Range("C" & i)
        Set dCell = Range("D" & i)
        Set eCell = Range("E" & i)

        For j = LBound(namesList, 1) + 1 To UBound(namesList, 1) '/ +1 for header row
            searchName = namesList(j, 1)
            displayName = namesList(j, 2)

            If NameIsInRange(searchName, cCell, dCell, eCell) Then
                resultRange = displayName
                Exit For '/ We found our result so we can terminate the loop early
            End If

        Next j

        i = i + 1

    Wend

End Sub

Public Function NameIsInRange(ByVal searchName As String, ByRef range1 As Range, range2 As Range, range3 As Range) As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    result = InStr(1, range1, searchName) Or InStr(1, range2, searchName) Or InStr(1, range3, searchName)

    NameIsInRange = result

End Function

Public Function GetCountryNamesTable() As Variant

    With wsCountryNames

        Dim topLeftCell As Range
        Set topLeftCell = .Cells(1, 1) '/ "A1"

        Dim finalRow As Long
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, topLeftCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim tableWidth As Long
        tableWidth = 2

        Dim tableRange As Range
        Set tableRange = .Range(topLeftCell, Cells(finalRow, topLeftCell.Column + tableWidth - 1))

    End With

    GetCountryNamesTable = tableRange

End Function
```

---

### **3rd Refactoring**

I'm going to put your search range in an Array:

```
Public Function GetSearchRange() As Variant

    With (codename of your sheet here, call it wsSearchSheet for now)

        Dim topLeftCell As Range
        Set topLeftCell = .Cells(1, 1) '/ "A1"

        Dim finalRow As Long
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row '/ "2" for "B" column

        Dim finalCol As Long
        finalCol = 5 '/ "E" column

        Dim tableRange As Range
        Set tableRange = .Range(topLeftCell, Cells(finalRow, finalCol))

    End With

    GetCountryNamesTable = tableRange

End Function
```

And Re-Jig the `IsInRange` function to deal with an array value instead:

```
Public Function ValueContainsString(ByVal valueToSearch As Variant, ByVal searchString As String) As Boolean

    ValueContainsString = InStr(1, CStr(valueToSearch), searchString)

End Function
```

And implement these changes to the main sub:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PullCountries()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    Dim namesList As Variant
    namesList = GetCountryNamesTable

    Dim searchNameCol As Long, displayNameCol As Long
    searchNameCol = 1
    displayNameCol = 2

    Dim searchArray As Variant
    searchArray = GetSearchValues

    Dim searchStartCol As Long, searchEndCol As Long
    searchStartCol = 3
    searchEndCol = 5

    Dim outputCol As Long
    outputCol = 1

    Dim foundMatch As Boolean

    Dim valueToSearch As Variant
    Dim searchName As String, displayName As String

    For i = LBound(searchArray, 1) To UBound(searchArray, 1)
        foundMatch = False

        For j = searchStartCol To searchEndCol
            valueToSearch = searchArray(i, j)

                For k = LBound(namesList, 1) + 1 To UBound(namesList, 1) '/ +1 for header row
                    searchName = namesList(k, searchNameCol)

                    If ValueContainsString(valueToSearch, searchName) Then
                        displayName = namesList(k, displayNameCol)
                        searchArray(i, outputCol) = displayName
                        foundMatch = True
                        Exit For '/ We found our result so we can terminate the loop early
                    End If
                Next k

            If foundMatch Then Exit For
        Next j
    Next i

    '/ Read output back to sheet. 
    For i = LBound(searchArray, 1) To UBound(searchArray, 1)
        Range("A" & i) = searchArray(i, outputCol)
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function ValueContainsString(ByVal valueToSearch As Variant, ByVal searchString As String) As Boolean

    ValueContainsString = InStr(1, CStr(valueToSearch), searchString)

End Function

Public Function GetCountryNamesTable() As Variant

    With wsCountryNames

        Dim topLeftCell As Range
        Set topLeftCell = .Cells(1, 1) '/ "A1"

        Dim finalRow As Long
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, topLeftCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim tableWidth As Long
        tableWidth = 2

        Dim tableRange As Range
        Set tableRange = .Range(topLeftCell, Cells(finalRow, topLeftCell.Column + tableWidth - 1))

    End With

    GetCountryNamesTable = tableRange

End Function

Public Function GetSearchValues() As Variant

    With (codename of your sheet here, call it wsSearchSheet for now)

        Dim topLeftCell As Range
        Set topLeftCell = .Cells(1, 1) '/ "A1"

        Dim finalRow As Long
        finalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row '/ "2" for "B" column

        Dim finalCol As Long
        finalCol = 5 '/ "E" column

        Dim tableRange As Range
        Set tableRange = .Range(topLeftCell, Cells(finalRow, finalCol))

    End With

    GetSearchValues = tableRange

End Function
```

Want to change your country names? Just change the values in your table. Your data moves about? Just change the `GetSearchValues` targets. You can extend either as far as you like.

Total number of values you now have to change in your code: Maybe 10. And then only if your sheet data moves around positions.

---

### Codenames Addendum

Codenames are big and clever. Every worksheet and workbook has a "name" that the user can see and change.

`MyCurrentWB.Worksheets("Country Names")`

is referencing a sheet name.

A Codename on the other hand is a secret name that can **only** be set/changed in the IDE.

[image]

the name in brackets is the "name". The name not in brackets is the "codename". It is set in the properties window.

[image]

If you give a sheet a codename then the user can change the name as much as they like, all you have to do is use

`wsCountryNames.Cells()`

in your code and it will keep running.

Comment: Awesome. This is great advice, given that I'm totally oblivious to naming conventions. What do you mean by "Don't Use :" Is there an issue with the line Else: i = i + 1?

Comment: Don't go anywhere. This got posted halfway through me writing it so more is coming. The problem with `:` is that it literally says to the compiler "Treat everything after the `:` as though it were on a new line". You should just put it on a new line and prevent any confusion.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused at the 2nd Refactoring. Running the updated code as is is giving me a Object required error for `Set topLeftCell = .Cells(1, 1)` 

Is this expected?

Comment: It's because it's expecting a **codename** (namely, `wsCountryNames`) to already exist.

Comment: I've added an addendum on codenames.

Comment: Thanks, Kaz. This works perfectly now (although I have not implemented the third refactoring yet). I'm currently seeing what changes I could make to have multiple countries pulled out if they occur. I'm considering having a new output spreadsheet, and using the insert command to give me multiple results. Any suggestions you have would be very welcome.

And finally, instead of putting my search range into an array, could I not just change the range to "all of row i" and have that increase in increments? 

Thanks,

Comment: You could, but then you're accessing the worksheet **every** time you set a new range, and accessing a worksheet is **slow**. Do it once (to put it in an array) and you'll never notice, do it 10,000 times and your sub will slow to a crawl.  w/rt multiple outputs: I would consider having a table(array) where each country gets a column and for each row, check off if each country appears in said row.

Answer (score 8):

You could improve readability by lining things up with line continuations:

```
If InStr(1, Range("C" & i), "Canada") Or _
   InStr(1, Range("D" & i), "Canada") Or _
   InStr(1, Range("E" & i), "Canada") _
Then
```

Now, if you're doing that 20 times, it's *still* a clunky piece of code.. just with less horizontal scrolling.

You noticed the repetition, that's good! Next step, is to eliminate it.

All branches do the same thing:

```
Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = country
i = i + 1
```

How about you introduce a variable for `country`, and only write that bit once?

```
'...some logic to determine the value of 'country'

Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = country
i = i + 1
```

---

You need the values from 3 cells - store them in local variables, and reuse *variables* instead of accessing the worksheet over and over: accessing a worksheet is **the** slowest thing Excel-VBA does.

```
'todo: rename to... probably what the headers are saying
Dim goodNameForColumnC As String
goodNameForColumnC = Range("C" & i).Value

Dim goodNameForColumnD As String
goodNameForColumnD = Range("D" & i).Value

Dim goodNameForColumnE As String
goodNameForColumnE = Range("E" & i).Value
```

Something bothers me here. `Range`, when used all by itself, is actually calling the `Application.Range` function, which implicitly refers to the active sheet. That's bad, especially if you have code that uses `Select` and `Activate` (which, luckily, you don't -- kudos for that!).

Never assume what the active sheet is going to be when your macro runs. If your code is supposed to run off `Sheet1`, then qualify the `Range` function call with `Sheet1`:

```
'todo: rename to... probably what the headers are saying
Dim goodNameForColumnC As String
goodNameForColumnC = Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value

Dim goodNameForColumnD As String
goodNameForColumnD = Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value

Dim goodNameForColumnE As String
goodNameForColumnE = Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value
```

Just doing that makes your code much less fragile.

---

So you have a number of strings you're looking for. Make an array for them:

```
Dim countries As Variant
countries = Array("Canada", "United Stated", "UK", "Spain", "Portugal", "Japan", "Greece", "Italy")
```

Now, what you really want to do, is to determine if either of the 3 cells you're looking in contains any of these strings, and if it does, you need to know what that string is. That really sounds like a job for a function.

Make another array for your cell values:

```
Dim cellValues As Variant
cellValues = Array(goodNameForColumnC, goodNameForColumnD, goodNameForColumnE)
```

Now you can pass that array as a parameter to a function that does just that:

```
Private Function ContainsAnyOf(ByRef cellValues(), ByRef countries(), ByRef outCountry As String) As Boolean

End Function
```

Notice the `out` prefix in `outCountry`? That's "the right way" to use *Hungarian Notation* - kudos for *not* using the "wrong way" in your variable names. Too often we see unreadable names with prefixes like `s` for `String`, `i` for `Integer`, `o` for `Object`, etc. But `out` here, means "this variable is really a return value".

So you can do this:

```
Dim country As String
If ContainsAnyOf(cellValues, countries, country) Then
    Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = country
    i = i + 1
End If
```

And be done with it.

What's the implementation like, you'll ask? Simple - it's all about loops, and *returning early*:

```
Private Function ContainsAnyOf(ByRef cellValues(), ByRef countries(), ByRef outCountry As String) As Boolean

    Dim valueIndex As Integer
    Dim countryIndex As Integer

    For valueIndex = LBound(cellValues) To UBound(cellValues)
        For countryIndex = LBound(countries) To UBound(countries)
            If InStr(1, cellValues(valueIndex), countries(countryIndex)) > 0 Then
                outCountry = countries(countryIndex)
                ContainsAnyOf = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next countryIndex
    Next valueIndex

    outCountry = vbNullString
    ContainsAnyOf = False
End Function
```

The function will return `True` when any of the cell values contains any of the country names, and the `outCountry` will be either an empty string or the country name that was found.

Best of all, if you need to add more countries, all you need to do is add items to the array!

---

That could leave your final code looking like this:

```
Public Sub PullCountries()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim currentRow As Long
    currentRow = 1

    Dim target As Range
    Dim countries As Variant
    countries = Array("Canada", "United Stated", "UK", "Spain", _
                      "Portugal", "Japan", "Greece", "Italy")

    'todo: rename to... probably what the headers are saying
    Dim goodNameForColumnC As String
    Dim goodNameForColumnD As String
    Dim goodNameForColumnE As String

    Dim cellValues As Variant
    Dim country As String

    While currentRow <= lastRow

        Set target = Sheet1.Range("B" & currentRow)

        goodNameForColumnC = Sheet1.Range("C" & currentRow).Value
        goodNameForColumnD = Sheet1.Range("D" & currentRow).Value
        goodNameForColumnE = Sheet1.Range("E" & currentRow).Value
        cellValues = Array(goodNameForColumnC, goodNameForColumnD, goodNameForColumnE)

        If ContainsAnyOf(cellValues, countries, country) Then
            target.Offset(0, -1).Value = country
        End If

        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome answer. These are great suggestions, and I'm really learning a lot. Putting your suggestions to use right now! Cheers!